# How do I inject a Class into a c# dll

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-8.0, dll-injection

I've a dll with a bunch of classes and methods, it's part of an executable.

The dll will include the following

```
public class MyDep: IMyDep 
{
  public void aMethod() {return;}
}
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
  public IMyDep Dep = new MyDep();
}
```

Now from another solution I will run MyApp.exe which will load the dll as one of its dependencies.

Before I run it I would like to define a mock `MyDep` class and inject it into the original dll.
Ideally I want to write this process entirely in c# and automate it.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: what did you try already? Mocking sounds like a good way, so please elaborate on where exactly you need help. And please also include how the above code relates to MyApp.exe.

Comment: Do you have access, so you can implement proper patterns for this, or are you looking to "hack" a dll that just is that broken?

Comment: I'm doing UI automation with appium, the Class deals with a windows driver that communicates with hardware, appium only runs executables and doesn't have any way to mock code in a simple fashion as far as I know.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain the code (the dll) is just a dependency of the executable

Comment: Can you change `MyClass`? Currently it has a strong dependency to `MyDep`, which is very hard to break.

Comment: mh, why? it's MyDep that I want to overwrite

Comment: you cannot just "override" a class that isn't designed to be overridden. And from what we see, it certainly is not designed that way, so you *need* to change it.

Comment: You *could* just set the public field to something different in your test, e.g. `var myClass = new MyClass(); myClass.Dep = whatever`. However that still will create an instance of `MyDep` when `MyClass` is *created*. I don't kno if that's a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256891/discussion-between-axeltherabbit-and-makepeacegreatagain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### UPDATE

Rather than creating a new solution I decided to use a compiler symbol at least I won't have too many solutions in the project.

I changed `MyDep` to

```
public class MyDep: IMyDep 
{
#if APPIUM
  public void aMethod() {
   runMockCode();
   return;
  }

#else
  public void aMethod() {
   runProductionCode();
   return;
  }

#endif
}
```

And I'll compile it with `donet build -p:APPIUM=true` for APPIUM testing

###### OLD

Looks like the only simple solution is to isolate `MyDep` into a separate project and add it as reference on the main project, this way it will compile as a standalone dll with just the things I need to mock.

I then create another project which is a copy of the project that I want to mock and I modified the methods that I needed to mock.

**NB**. the output dll must compile with the same name of the original dll.
In VS -> project properties -> Application -> Assembly name

I needed this to mock some code that communicates with hardware using appium for UI tests.

Before I start appium I compile the project into a test folder, and then replace the dll with the mock dll.